# Xcode (iPhone) build warnings

Tags: iphone, xcode, build

I just installed Xcode 3.2.3.  I have a first generation iPhone that I use for testing purposes.  It has 3.1.3 installed on the iPhone.  On the build droplist near the upper left, there don't seem to be as many choices as there were on the older version i.e. base SDK to build against.  Now there is only Device/Simulator, Debug/Release as choices.  When I build and try to install it on the iPhone, I am now getting a warning "The info.plist for application at (the path) specifies a minimum OS version of 3.2, which is too high to be installed on iPhone and get a "can't install application" error. When I look in the .plist, I cannot find where 3.2 is specified anywhere.

Also, there is a build warning of "warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2'."

What do I need to do to be able to test again?  Hopefully I don't have to purchase a new iPhone or iPod touch just for testing purposes.

TIA,
Linda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use SDK 4 with an old iPod Touch 1st Gen running 3.1.3 and it works fine.

The trick is to set the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" build setting to 3.1.3.

Comment: Should this be in the droplist near the upper left in Xcode?  If so, for some reason, my installation of Xcode does not have all of the choices that I had on a previous installation.

Comment: BTW, what I just installed was xcode_3.2.3_and_iphone_sdk_4__final

Comment: Select your project in the Groups & Files pane. Right-click and Get Info. Click on the "Build" tab. Scroll down to the "iPhone OS Deployment Target" build setting. Set its value to 3.1.3.